# What is the Sherwood binary search algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, binary-search

I took my final for Java programming on Monday and passed it. I just got the graded hard copy today and my instructor said I should have used the Sherwood binary search algorithm instead of regular binary search. Does anyone have a template of this algorithm? I have tried searching on the web for it but only get the meaning of it and not an actual template or copy of the copy so I can run it.

Thanks necromancer I got it working and see why he may have wanted it.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the notion of the sherwood binary search :)

Comment: in a binary search you have a `low` and `high` from which  you compute `mid = (low + high) / 2`. in the sherwood version just use `mid = low + random.nextInt(high - low + 1)` but adjust it for boundary conditions, i. e. may be you never want to pick `low` or `high` itself but only the numbers in between them, in which case adjust the expression i gave earlier.

Comment: if you post your attempt based on my comment above, you will surely get an answer.

Comment: ahhh ok that makes sense. I wonder why he would want me to use that instead of binary though? I guess to make me think, I'm sure he went over it once in class.

Comment: Thanks necromancer I appreciate it.

Comment: unless you are learning about probabilistic algorithms, you will not need it. i've been programming in the industry for years and never encountered it or used it. The usefulness of the technique is for the following reason: if the element is in the array, then the binary search will find it in one step if it is in the middle and many more steps if it is say in the second position. Therefore the speed of the search depends upon the position of the element. Using the Sherwood technique makes the speed independent of the position of the element, and based on pure luck.

Comment: Read more here: http://books.google.com/books?id=FUeGDaqjk5oC&lpg=PA383&ots=qC7-IkcBre&dq=sherwood%20version%20binary%20search&pg=PA383#v=onepage&q=sherwood%20version%20binary%20search&f=false

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll definitely check out those books.

Comment: Congrats on getting it working and posting your code, and good job figuring it out *after* your test. A+! :D

Comment: Did your instructor, or anyone, *teach* you the Sherwood algorithm? If not, it's a pretty pointless remark. If so, you should have recognized it. And there's no "should" about it, unless something was mentioned in the question. It reduces the running time of the worst case and increases it for the best case.

Comment: As I stated previously I'm sure he did but given how I was taking 5 classes in the summer semester to graduate early my mind was all over the place. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @EJP it is easy to skip some part of the curriculum. A sick day, struggling with another course, or, in my case, simply being lazy or having a very boring lecture, would lead to my not learning or not bothering to learn some part of the curriculum that I thought was unimportant. Sometimes the appreciation would come later. Whatever be the OP's reason, I'd commend the OP for the passion to learn at the end of the day. :)

Comment: @EJP wait, reduces the running time of the worst case? That doesn't sound right. With bad input and random choices, this looks to me like it could degenerate to linear time. Did you maybe mean it exactly the other way around?

Comment: @xedocx please post a complete answer to your question instead of editing it. I believe the question should remain in its previous version and the edit should come as an answer with a bit more detail for instance what is a sherwood binary search and why is it better(i.e. the explanation of  `and see why he may have wanted it.`)

Comment: Ok, I can do that. I'll edit out the soultion and post it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sherwood algorithm is a modified version of the standard binary search. In search algorithms there is always a best case scenario and a worst case scenario that could happen.
When performing a binary search there are always some locations that will require a fail in order to be checked. This number of fail checks will vary greatly depending on the number of elements that you are searching through.

The reasoning behind these fails is due to the fact of the core statement of a binary search is:

middle = (first + last) / 2;

With the Sherwood algorithm that standard structure is replaced by the concept of randomness.
The core statement behind the Sherwood algorithm is:

middle = first + rand.nextInt(last - first + 1);

If you were searching a list of 1000 elements with the Sherwood algorithm and it picked the middle as 250th element. The value that you are searching for could be < the 250th element so in turn 75 percent of the elements in the list would be discarded rather than just 50 percent. At the same time the value could be greater than the 250th element and only 25 percent of the elements in the list would be discarded.

The concept is that the Sherwood algorithm will reduce the time of the worst case scenario and yet increase the time of the best case.

That's not to say that it is better than the binary search, but instead just showing another way of completing it. I believe that was the reasoning behind my professor's meaning because in his class he likes to see us think outside of the box and show multiple ways to get to one solution. You should always have multiple paths in case one path is blocked.

```
public static void sherwoodSearch(int[ ] array, int value)
    {
        int first, last, middle, position, count;
        boolean found;

        //set the inital values.
        first = 0;
        last = array.length-1;
        position = -1;
        found = false;
        count =1;
        Random rand = new Random();
        //search for the value
        while (!found && first <= last)
        {
            count++;
            middle = first + rand.nextInt(last - first + 1);
            if (array[middle] == value)
            {
                found = true;
                position = middle;
            }
            else if (array[middle] > value)
                last = middle -1;
            else
                first = middle + 1;
            if (first <= last)
            {
                System.out.println("The number was found in array subscript" + position);
                System.out.println("The sherwood search found the number after " + count +
                    " comparisons.");

            }
            else
                System.out.println("Sorry, the number is not in this array.  The sherwood search made "
                    +count  + " comparisons.");
        }
    }
```